# What is with the null character in reverse string program?

Tags: c, arrays, string, reverse

I had to make a simple program to reverse a string. I eventually got this code from my own understanding but also help from google since I couldn't originally get it to work. It runs fine and outputs as it should and I understand all of it except for the `reverse[j] = '\0'` statement. 
I kept getting symbols in my output when I didn't state it but I want to know how this works. Can anyone explain please?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char original[20], reverse[20];
    int length, i, j;

    printf("Enter a string:\n");
    gets(original); 

    length = strlen(original);

    for (i = length - 1, j= 0; i >= 0; i--, j++)
        reverse[j] = original[i];

    reverse[j] = '\0';  //I don't know what this statement does exactly

    printf("The string reversed is:\n %s\n", reverse);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by reading the chapter about strings in your C programming book.

Comment: I have but I wanted a simple explanation. My textbook doesn't explain well.

Comment: Then get a new book. Any beginner-level book which doesn't mention nul termination of C strings is bad.

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/181505/35384

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want that a character array would contain a string then it has to have the terminating zero.

For example function `strlen` that is used in your program counts characters in a character array before the terminating zero.

Also function `printf` used with the format specifier `%s` outputs characters from a character array until the terminating zero will be encountered.

For example if you have an array like this

```
char s[10] = "Hello";
```

then the call `strlen( s )` returns 5 instead of 10. And call printf( "%s\n", s ); outputs 6 characters (including the new line character).

Consider this demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s[10] = "Hello";

    printf( "%d\n", printf( "%s\n", s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello
6
```

This initialization

```
char s[10] = "Hello";
```

is fully equivalent to

```
char s[10] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0'};
```

If you need to reverse the string stored in the array it is obvious that you need to reverse characters before the first terminating zero. And if you want to copy the string in the reversed order to another character array you need to append the destination array with the terminating zero.

This loop

```
for (i = length - 1, j= 0; i >= 0; i--, j++)
    reverse[j] = original[i];
```

copies in the reversed order all characters except the terminating zero from the original character array starting with the last character before the terminating zero to the destination character array. You need to append the destination character array with the terminating zero

```
reverse[j] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thank You! So basically it's marking the end of the string instead of it going until the end of array size?

Comment: @nedst3r Yes. Function strlen used in your program searches the terminating zero and counts the number of characters before the terminating zero. For example if you have an array char s[10] = "Hello"; then strlen will return 5 though the array has 10 characters.

Comment: @nedst3r There is no end of array size, if you omit the terminating null and try to print the string it will just keep accessing sequential memory until a segfault will occur

Comment: @VladfromMoscow what a brilliant and educational answer - many C textbooks would wish to have such explanations (including the elegant call of `printf()` as optional argument to `printf()`. Yet, with all the due respect to your indisputable work and reputation, please don't mind my asking: would it be more legitimate naming the terminating `'\0'` character _nul character_ or _zero character_ ? AFAIK, _zero character_ is just `'0'`.

Comment: @user3078414 Maybe it could be said terminating zero-character.:)

Answer (score 2):

In C, a string always has a `\0` at the end. Read [why](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) and [how](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx8.html).

Answer (score 2):

The `\0` is not really a character. It's the way a [c](/questions/tagged/c) program mark the end of a string. So if you only want to reverse a string you don't have to move this character at the begining of the reversed string.

```
original string: hello\0
reverse string : olleh\0
```

Answer (score 0):

\0 is for null terminating the string. This will mark the end of the string. If it is not null terminated, the data in the succeeding locations will also wrongly treat as part of string.

Comment: "*This will help to mark*", it does not  just "*help*" it "***is***" the mark.

Comment: Corrected :).  Thanks